# jquery find function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

How I can select a specific a element id whit jquery find?Or it is even possible?

HTML:

```
 <div id="bar">
    <a id="1" href="#"></a>
    <a id="2" href="#"></a>
    <a id="3" href="#"></a>
    <a id="4" href="#"></a>
    </div>

Javascript:


 $('#bar a').find('id',2).css("background-color","blue");
```

But dosen't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IDs **must be unique**, so simply use `$('#2')` to select the element. There is usually no need to make an ID selector more specific and doing so would just slow it down.

Besides that, unless you are using HTML5, an ID cannot start with a number. Use e.g. `whatever-2` instead of just `2`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#bar a#1')
```

will select the  with id '1'.

Alltho, #1 is not a valid ID-name, they can't begin with a number, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Either finding a descendant

```
$('#bar').find('#2').css("background-color","blue");
```

or filtering a descendant

```
$('#bar a').filter('#2').css("background-color","blue");
```

or getting via context:

```
var parent = $('#bar');
$('#2',parent).css("background-color","blue");
```

or get it directly! since IDs are unique anyway (unless you move this element often in the page, which is why you need the parent):

```
$('#2').css("background-color","blue");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use eq method for get element by index http://api.jquery.com/eq/

```
 $('#bar a').eq(2).css("background-color","blue");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no point using find() to search for id, since by definition id has to be unique. Find() function is better when you want to find a class or html tag elements inside any parent element. Good example from documentation: when you want to change css of all spans inside specific element, use find:

```
 $("p").find("span").css('color','red');
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try  $("#bar").find("#2").css("background-color", "blue");

and as ThiefMaster says u can always use $("#id").css("background-color", "blue");